# Vue how to use get method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to send `get` method from Vue in html file. My code looks:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <p>{{something}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#myDiv',
            data: function(){
                return{
                    something: ''
                }
            },
            ready: function(){
                this.getValue();
            },
            methods: {
                getValue: function(){
                    var value = value;
                    this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                        .success(function(value){
                            this.$set('value',value);
                        })
                        .error(function(err){
                            value.log(err);
                        });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

How is it possible to put response in `something` in `div` with `id="myDiv"` just as string? (for example `json`:

```
{
   "name":"Jon",
   "age":1
}
```

There is no error in console but my screen is totally blank.

@Update:
result is:

[image]

@Update2
my html file (by your code):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
          <div v-if="response.userId">
            {{ response.userId }}
            {{ response.id }}
            {{ response.title }}
            {{ response.body }}
          </div>
          <div v-if="response.error">
            <p>Request failed</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#myDiv',
          data: {
                response: {}
          },
          created() {
          this
           .$http
           .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
           .then(function(response) {
             console.log(response)
             this.$set('response', response.data)
           })
          }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.2.0/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
          <div v-if="response.userId">
            {{ response.userId }}
            {{ response.id }}
            {{ response.title }}
            {{ response.body }}
          </div>
          <div v-if="response.error">
            <p>Request failed</p>
          </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
          el: '#myDiv',
          data: {
            response: {}
          },
          created() {
          this
           .$http
           .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
           .then(function(response) {
             console.log(response)
             this.response = response.data
           })
          }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I used your code but the result is: `{{ response.message }} {{ response.status }}{{ response.error }}`

Comment: I put result in my post

Comment: Refresh your page, I updated the answer. Data should be an object not function, here is the working fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/177/

Comment: I did it (with clean cache) but its still nothing. Could you check my current code? (is in my post - @update2)

Comment: You didn't add script for `vue-resource` module which you are using it to get resource from server. I updated the head section of html check it now, it will and should work. @littlewombat

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you very much. Could you send me any documentation or tutorial for `vue-resource` (or anything for http methods in Vue)